# M expression for SSIS equivalent

Tags: ssis, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I've just started exploring DAX on PowerBI; so please excuse if this query sounds too novice to expert users. DAX functions are too 'different' if coming from a SQL background, hence the query.

In SSIS I'm using a function to replace values in a column based on a string (more so, an error in the value). I'm using the below to do the job easily:

```
Column2 = SUBSTRING([Column1],1,FINDSTRING([Column1],";#",1) - 1)
```

Even after looking at the `Text` functions on [Microsoft help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powerquery-m/text-functions).

for almost an hour trying to understand; I couldn't for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're confusing DAX and M. You linked to M documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what to say here; don't know what M is. Can you guide me to appropriate help link for my query?

Comment: They're both part of Power BI. M is for the query editor and DAX is for writing measures after all the data is loaded. Where are you trying to do the transformation?

Comment: I'm trying to add a new column based on the calculation in the query. On Power Query Editor, I'm trying to add a `Custom Column` where I should write the expression.

Comment: OK. That is M. I've added that tag for you but you should probably edit your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analogous expression in M would be

```
Text.Middle([Column1], 1, Text.PositionOf([Column1], ";#") - 1)
```

But you could also use `Text.Start` instead since you're starting at 1 or make it even simpler with `Text.BeforeDelimiter`:

```
Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1], ";#")
```

In DAX, you'd use `MID`/`LEFT` instead of `Text.Start`/`Text.Middle` and `FIND` or `SEARCH` (depending on if you need case-sensitivity or not) instead of `Text.PositionOf`.

```
LEFT ( [Column1], SEARCH ( ";#", [Column1] ) - 1 )
```

Either way, the logic is nearly identical but you just have different function names.